# Radio button along with char field

Tags: django, django-forms

I need to create a django form where field is the combination of radio button and text box. Say:

0 choice 1
   TEXT BOX - contains model form field value

0 choice 2
   TEXT BOX - contains model form field value
(Please refer attachment)

I want to get the value of Text box on selection of choices (choice 1 or choice 2)
Both the Textboxes (CharField in forms.py)are set to required=False as in forms only one will have the value.
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: 1. use jquery to change value of ur radio button. say ur radio button is like this:  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>. then u can use $('select_ur_radio_button_here').val('myval').now submitting the form will submit it with changed value.

Comment: a better answer is a custome widget, but that will be long and comes with chances of failed attempt for not so-smart people like me :P

Comment: Thanks @vijayshanker